# [Flutter]The height of Chinese and English in the same paragraph is inconsistent with the height of Chinese

Tags: flutter

Text(
'You have pushed the butgton this ma啊啊大啊的大ny times:',
style: TextStyle(
backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
fontFamily: "Roboto",
),
),

[run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fJs4.png)

Comment: I dunt think Roboto have supported chinese. The different height is usually because of using different family. You may try to use another one which support eng and chi at the same time. ref: https://fonts.google.com/

Comment: @CbL First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I already knew the fontFamily problem in yesterday’s test, but I don’t know why yesterday when I tested on fonts.google.com, I got the conclusion that "Roboto" supports Chinese, but now I can’t get it. This is the conclusion.
Yesterday I tried to use "NotoSansSC", the line height of all characters is the same, but the lowercase letter'g' is not a single layer (it needs to be displayed as a single layer). do you have any good advice?